# Is threre a way to comunicate between threads and exchange information like a getter method inside the runnable, in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a way to communicate between thread such as get variables with getters as they are being updated in a different thread

For example if im loading images in a runnable thread like so:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
     //Ido the loading here
    }
}
```

is there a way i can communicate to that like get a value of a var for example:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
     //Ido the loading here
name = "dsad";
    }
public void getName(){ return name }
}
```

but it dosnt seen to work

Comment: You need to create a type, `Runnable` has no other public method or fields besides `run()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new public type.  Using an anonymous class means no other class can see its methods, as there's no type besides `Runnable` that they can see.

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable(){
    private volatile String name;
    public void run(){
     //I do the loading here
         name = "dsad";
    }
    public void getName(){ return name }
}
```

Comment: it isn't safe as `name` is not synchronized.

Comment: The `volatile` keyword guarantees visibility only amongst threads, but does not provide for mutual exclusion.  Are you certain that all modifications to the `String` are atomic?  Even with `volatile` you can be vulnerable to races.

Comment: String are immutable in Java, and that guarantees visibility. For other objects, Java's visibility semantics guarantee *happens-before* for all writes made up to the point where the volatile is assigned, including writes an object makes internally.  So as long as the object assigned to `name` isn't modified further, it's thread safe. @scottb

Answer (score 1):

As for thread communicating, there's `java.util.concurrent.Exchanger`.

In your particular case, it also possible to use CompletableFuture from Java 8, since Exchanger allows multiple communications (both of threads continue executing), which is possibly not your case.

Manually creating threads may cause different issues:

- creating thread each time is expensive operation,
- creating lots of threads which run at the same time involves possible scheduler problems, memory issues (each thread has it's own stack, ...),
- publishing values not in safe way (see Safe Publication and Safe Initialization topics) may cause data races, which are really bad

So, combination of `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` and `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture` may allow you thread-safe and easy readable way to perform asynchronous loading.

Comment: Using `java.util.concurrent` is actually a better idea, but I think the OP's question is really about why adding a public method to an anonymous class doesn't "work," and that's basically why I gave the answer I did.

Comment: true but i would like some one to share a method of comunicatig between threads too.